# Create a property as list in neo4j node?

Tags: java, neo4j

For better understanding of question, consider a scenario where nodes are persons and edges are MET_ON, so two persons can meet none, one or multiple times. Whenever personA meets personB for the first time, an edge is created between them and a property `timestamp` is set. Now whenever they meet again, the new `timestamp` has to be appended. For this I require `timestamp` to be a list.

Comment: Just a design question: why don't you create an edge every time they met? That edge will have a timestamp property and you can then filter by time in the future...

Comment: There are many ways to model something like this depending on how you plan to query later but I would probably start with what Marco mentions, each meeting as a distinct edge. I answered anyway so you can try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
// Peter meets Paul
MERGE (peter:User {name:"Peter"})
MERGE (paul:User {name:"Paul"})
MERGE (peter)-[m:MEETS]-(paul)
    ON CREATE SET m.timestamp = [timestamp()]
    ON MATCH SET m.timestamp = m.timestamp + timestamp()
```

Comment: Thanks!! Any help for java embedded api?

Comment: See [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-cypher-java.html) for the documentation on executing cypher queries from Java. Remember to [use parameters](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-cypher-parameters-java.html).